# Spring boot application, component scan missing some @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, java-ee-6

I am new to Spring and I am kind of lost right now.
In this SpringBoot app, I got 3 classes, all 3 inherit from a top abstract class. 
The three classes are annotated @Component and are in the same package.

```
AbstractClass
|
|-- @Component ClassA extends abstractClass
|-- @Component ClassB extends abstractClass
|-- @Component ClassC extends abstractClass
```

Each class starts some threads to do some background work. 
So basically AbstractClass handles the threads starting logic, while each Class will have its own ExecutorService, and a number of threads, and will implement the behaviour of the runnable object that will be submitted to the ExecutorService.

Here is my Spring Configuration :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.test"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And all my classes are in the package com.myapp.test.listeners.

Funny thing is : ClassA starts and works perfectly.
ClassB and ClassC are not started, and do not even appear in the logs.

I already lost 3 hours on that... If one of you has an idea...
Thanks!

Comment: You can try with `@ComponentScan({ "package-name" })` annotation and replace the package-name with your own package name of these three classes.

Comment: How do they start? Do you have @PostContruct or some way to execute code when bean is ready? Or do you autowire it somewhere first and then invoke a method?

Comment: Please add your Spring configuration

Comment: if you are using xml configuration for your beans, you can add the following to your dispatcher-servlet.xml    <context:component-scan base-package="package-1, package-2,..." />

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your messages.

My configuration is an empty `@SpringBootApplication`.

Where I set `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.test"})`.

And all my classes are in a package called "com.myapp.test.listeners".

Thanks,

Comment: @Faraz yeah I have the constructor, and an other method, annotated with `@PostConstruct`, to start the listening threads.

Comment: you dont need ComponentScan annotation. it is already in  SpringBootApplication annotation

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem, I don't know exactly what was causing the issue... But I know what solves it : one of my class isn't used for now, so I used `Excutors.newFixedThreadPool(0)` to create its ExecutorService member... which triggers an exception (that wasn't displayed in the logs).
Strangely, it kept an other Component to be scanned and created... But now it works.

Comment: There is nothing strange here. Spring creates beans in fail fast manner. Once it cannot create a bean it throws exception and stops any further processing